# Rotate text in outer margin of device region

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to add text to the right outer margin of multiple plots that is parallel to the axis but oriented towards the center of the plot (the orientation of the words "red" and "blue" in the below plot:

```
par(mfcol=2:1)

curve(sin,-2*pi,2*pi,col=2)
limits <- par("usr")
text(limits[2]+.25, mean(limits[3:4]),
     "red", srt=270, xpd=T)
curve(sin,-2*pi,2*pi,col=4)
text(limits[2]+.25, mean(limits[3:4]),
     "blue", srt=270, xpd=T)
mtext("Color of line",side=4,outer=T)
```

[image: toy example]

If the `mtext` function used the `srt` parameter rather than `las` (which was apparently the case for S plus), this would be trivial and the above workaround using `usr` would be unnecessary. But I'd like to be able to orient text in the outer margin ("Color of line" above) this same way, which I appear to be unable to do even manually with text (using `xpd=T` still constrains the text to the most recent figure region rather than the device region).

Is there a way to do this that doesn't require using `layout` as in [the answer of @mrflick here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24085166/4181415)? This seems like it should be trivial but I don't see how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

To find the y coordinates of the center of the device, you can use `grconvertY` to convert from "normalized device coordinates" (`"ndc"`; ranges from 0 to 1) to user coordinates.

The x value is here simply adjusted with an appropriate factor (e.g. `limits[2] * 1.2`).

```
windows()
par(mfrow = c(2, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 2))

curve(sin, -2*pi, 2*pi, col = 2)
limits <- par("usr")
text(limits[2] + 0.25, mean(limits[3:4]),
     "red", srt = 270, xpd = TRUE)
curve(sin, -2*pi, 2*pi, col = 4)
text(limits[2] + 0.25, mean(limits[3:4]),
     "blue", srt = 270, xpd = TRUE)

text(x = limits[2] * 1.2, y = grconvertY(0.5, from = "ndc"),
     labels = "color of line", xpd = NA, srt = 270)
```

[image]

---

Please see previous revisions if you rather want to calculate y position from user coordinates (`"usr"`) and plot margins (`"mai"`).

Comment: @Richard Border Forgot about `"ndc"` - please see updated answer.

Comment: @Richard Border Please let me know if my answer doesn't provide the desired result. Cheers